# Method to call two functions (one stdcall)

Tags: c++

I have two functions to create a beep. One calls the standard beep function and the other uses a library to write directly to ports. I'm trying to find a slick way of choosing which function to call based on a variable.

The standard beep function is defined as

```
BOOL stdcall Beep(
  _In_ DWORD dwFreq,
  _In_ DWORD dwDuration
);
```

Where as my function is:

```
void NewBeep(
   unsigned int freq, 
   int ms
);
```

At the moment I just have two almost identical functions but calling correct code.

Comment: `if (condition)` isn't sufficient because... ?

Comment: Overload your functions or use different function names.

Comment: Do you want to determine it *dynamically*, or *statically* (i.e., at compile-time)?

Answer (score 3):

You could just make a wrapper function like so:

```
BOOL BeepWrapper (int freq, int ms) {
  BOOL useStdFct = FALSE;
  if (useStdFct) {
    Beep (freq, ms);
  } else {
    NewBeep (freq, ms);
  }
}
```

you could make this to a preprocessor define so it's not hard coded what is used

Other option is to use default parameter so you could change it in code by just giving another parameter. Like this:

```
BOOL BeepWrapper (int freq, int ms, BOOL useStdFct = FALSE) {
  if (useStdFct) {
    Beep (freq, ms);
  } else {
    NewBeep (freq, ms);
  }
}
```

With preprocessor define:

```
//Somewhere in code
#define USE_STD_FCT FALSE
//or in your compiler config
// -DUSE_STD_FCT=FALSE

BOOL BeepWrapper (int freq, int ms) {
#ifdef USE_STD_FCT FALSE
    Beep (freq, ms);
#else
    NewBeep (freq, ms);
#endif
}
```

Comment: Your `beepWrapper` function will always use the `NewBeep` function.

Comment: must be chanched every time you want to call the other one or you make a define so you can change it by just compilling it with an other parameter

Comment: `BOOL useStdFct = FALSE;` is the problem. Move that to the parameters list or don't declare it as a local variable. Other than that your approach above is a good one.

Comment: Added another way to my answer :)

Comment: @MadddinTribleD And now, if you could show the example for `you could make this to a preprocessor define so it's not hard coded what is used`, that would be, truly complete answer, in my eyes.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius ok like this XD

Comment: @MadddinTribleD Well, what I was thinking was - suggesting to pass the define to a compiler (common options, to most of the compilers are -D, or -d), to avoid any hardcoding, but that's just nitpicking :)

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius didn't know the argument out of my mind. I us Visual Studio so i get a nice box to put it in :)

Comment: @MadddinTribleD I understand that, but everything you put in the boxes, in VS, gets transformed to command line arguments, eventually. And the argument for defines, there, is `/D`.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius i know. Feeling sorry for not knowing it out of my mind. XD